# Programmatically add canvas panels to a C# UWP page

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm creating a UWP Page in VS 2017 with C# and I want to run repeat the following Canvas Code for every user (no more than 20) from a Data Base to create a series of User Tiles:

```
  <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Margin="34,73,1532,625" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Fill="#3458a5" Width="280" Height="110" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Jill Brown" FontWeight="SemiBold" Canvas.Top="20" Foreground="white" FontSize="26"/>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Senior Lounge Host" Canvas.Top="60" Foreground="white" FontSize="16"/>
        <Button Content="Log in" Tag="1" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="78" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#CC4A7BE5" Foreground="White" Width="78" Click="buttonLogInClick"/>
    </Canvas>
```

It looks fine but I need to be able to create this when the page initialises. In Bootstrap Terms we're talking Cards with float left but with UWP I have no idea.

Comment: Why not Use a `GridView` and Create a `DataTemplate` with Above canvas, Bind the data you retrieve from DataBase and it will repeat itself?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code from the project I'm currently working on. It uses the Bladeview Control and WrapPanel Panel from the UWP Community Toolkit (Use nuget to add it to your project it if you don't already have it) to create the effect I believe you're going for with the dynamically generated canvases.

I would also recommend downloading the "UWP Sample App" from the Windows Store if you haven't already. It's demonstrates the controls available with the Community Toolkit and provides the code for them. It also offers code and documentation for a lot of helpful features you may want for your app.

The sample app will also give you a demo of the bladeview control I'm talking about.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer Height="764"  Width="776" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <controls:BladeView x:Name="UserBladeView" BladeMode="Normal" ItemsSource="{x:Bind UserDataBase}" Height="auto" Width="767" > <!-- ItemSource Should be the Observable Collection containing your user objects -->
        <controls:BladeView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <wrapPanel:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="auto"  Width="765" Margin="5"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </controls:BladeView.ItemsPanel>
        <controls:BladeView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Product"> <!-- This  should correspond to the namespace the class that represents your users resides in xmlns:local="using:yournamespace"-->
            <controls:BladeItem x:Name="UserTiles"
                                IsOpen="True"
                                TitleBarVisibility="Collapsed" Width="365" Height="575" Visibility="Visible" Background="#FF1D1919" BorderBrush="#FF5D5D5D"  BorderThickness="2" Margin="5">
              <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371" Margin="0,0,-10,-4"  >
                    <TextBlock Margin="2,2,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="UserFirstName" Text="{Binding FirstName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" Width="308" FontSize="36" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="UserLastName" Text="{Binding LastName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="316" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" Visibility="Visible"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="UserTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="316" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" Visibility="Visible"/>
                    <Image Margin="5" x:Name="UserImage" Source="{Binding UserHeadShot}" Height="100" Width="auto" />
              </StackPanel>
            </controls:BladeItem>
        </DataTemplate>
        </controls:BladeView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:BladeView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The ItemSource within the BladeView Control should be the ObservableCollection holding your user objects and within the BladeItem your bindings should represent the properties you want to display.

What this will do is create a BladeItem containing all of the bound properties in your class for each object in the collection. The WrapPanel will make sure the BladeViewer displays a new line of BladeItems when necessary.